# Obtener los datos de un array que es un subObjecto dentro de un objecto de una colección en mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Dado este array que es una colección en Mongo, como puedo hacer una consulta para obtener únicamente los datos del atributo 'respuestas'?.

Estos son los datos de la colección

```
[
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c65b5b6b02ea75c7c255d01"),
    "pregunta" : "¿Hola esto es una pregunta de prueba?",
    "categoriaId" : "",
    "informacionAdicional" : "esto es una prueba",
    "userId" : "erika_elena9@hotmail.com",
    "fecha" : ISODate("2019-02-14T18:38:46.565Z"),
    "cantidadVisitas" : 0,
    "respuestas" : [],
    "fechaCreacion" : ISODate("2019-02-14T18:38:46.565Z"),
    "usuarioCreacion" : "admin",
    "fechaModificacion" : Date(-62135596800000),
    "usuarioModificacion" : ""
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c6af0edb02ea75fb848dc61"),
    "pregunta" : "¿Hola esto es una pregunta de prueba?",
    "categoriaId" : "",
    "informacionAdicional" : "bla bla bla",
    "usuarioId" : "lesolano@bancolombia.com.co",
    "genero" : "hombre",
    "edad" : 28,
    "fecha" : ISODate("2019-02-18T17:52:45.362Z"),
    "visitas" : 0,
    "respuestas" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c6afdc5b02ea75fb848dc63"),
            "respuesta" : "Esta es una respuesta de prueba",
            "usuarioId" : "5c474fb4b02ea70694ad189e",
            "fecha" : ISODate("2019-02-18T18:47:33.907Z"),
            "likes" : 1,
            "dislikes" : 0,
            "fechaCreacion" : ISODate("2019-02-18T18:47:33.907Z"),
            "usuarioCreacion" : "5c474fb4b02ea70694ad189e",
            "fechaModificacion" : Date(-62135596800000),
            "usuarioModificacion" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c6aff26b02ea75fb848dc65"),
            "respuesta" : "ddd",
            "usuarioId" : "5c474fb4b02ea70694ad189e",
            "fecha" : ISODate("2019-02-18T18:53:26.808Z"),
            "likes" : 2,
            "dislikes" : 0,
            "fechaCreacion" : ISODate("2019-02-18T18:53:26.808Z"),
            "usuarioCreacion" : "5c474fb4b02ea70694ad189e",
            "fechaModificacion" : Date(-62135596800000),
            "usuarioModificacion" : ""
        }
    ],
    "fechaCreacion" : ISODate("2019-02-18T17:52:45.362Z"),
    "usuarioCreacion" : "admin",
    "fechaModificacion" : Date(-62135596800000),
    "usuarioModificacion" : ""
}
```

]

Y esto es lo que quiero obtener

```
[ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c6afdc5b02ea75fb848dc63"),
            "respuesta" : "Esta es una respuesta de prueba",
            "usuarioId" : "5c474fb4b02ea70694ad189e",
            "fecha" : ISODate("2019-02-18T18:47:33.907Z"),
            "likes" : 1,
            "dislikes" : 0,
            "fechaCreacion" : ISODate("2019-02-18T18:47:33.907Z"),
            "usuarioCreacion" : "5c474fb4b02ea70694ad189e",
            "fechaModificacion" : Date(-62135596800000),
            "usuarioModificacion" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c6aff26b02ea75fb848dc65"),
            "respuesta" : "ddd",
            "usuarioId" : "5c474fb4b02ea70694ad189e",
            "fecha" : ISODate("2019-02-18T18:53:26.808Z"),
            "likes" : 2,
            "dislikes" : 0,
            "fechaCreacion" : ISODate("2019-02-18T18:53:26.808Z"),
            "usuarioCreacion" : "5c474fb4b02ea70694ad189e",
            "fechaModificacion" : Date(-62135596800000),
            "usuarioModificacion" : ""
        }
    ]
```

Si observamos solo quiero obtener los datos que están dentro del objecto respuestas filtrando por el _id 5c6af0edb02ea75fb848dc61 del objeto padre.

Buscando en google encontré esta forma pero me devuelve el atributo respuestas y yo solo quiero lo que esta dentro del objecto respuestas. Como lo haría?. Gracias

```
db.getCollection('preguntas').find({"_id" : ObjectId("5c6af0edb02ea75fb848dc61")}, {"respuestas": 1})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

verifica bien si has cargado correctamente los documentos en la colección, al hacer una prueba en una consola de mongodb funciona correctamente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola rodrigo, efectivamente esa es la respuesta que yo obtengo, pero yo lo que quiero es que me devuelva únicamente los datos dentro del objeto respuestas. osea que me devuelva únicamente estos datos de esta forma que comento en la pregunta.. Quiero que los datos comiencen con [ ...] y no con "respuestas" : [... ]

Esto con el fin de que el objecto que tengo en mi backend es netamente de los objectos que están en el array respuestas.

Comment: dependiendo del lenguaje del backend, puedes hacer el tratamiento luego de recibida la da, cosa que tu arreglo contenga la información: arreglo = retorno["respuestas"], por ejemplo, considierando que retorno contenga el response de la consulta

Comment: quise decir: "puedes hacer el tratamiento luego de recibida la data", debes recordar que MongoDB su base es objeto JSON, asi que siempre te retornara en ese formato la información  (clave:valor)

Comment: Vale rodrigo, comprendo perfectamente lo que me dices y puedo hacerlo desde el backend, pero en ese orden de ideas, no hay forma de hacer lo que quiero directamente desde una consulta mongodb?

Comment: por la documentación que he leído, ese es el único formato de salida, JSON, o sea {"clave":"valor"}

Comment: @RodrigoBurgosMella, estás en un error, JSON no es el único formato de salida que provee Mongo. El formato de salida dependerá de la consulta que realices. Por ejemplo: `db.collection.count()` devuelve un valor numérico. Saludos

Comment: Sin embargo `distinct` es un `aggregation` y devuelve un `Array`

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener los datos del campo `respuestas` de tu documento y mostrarlos en un `array`, puedes usar el método [`distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/).

Según la documentación, el método `distinct()` encuentra los valores distintos para un campo específico dentro de una colección o vista y devuelve el resultado en un `array`.

El método `distinct()` recibe 3 parámetros:

- `field`: El campo sobre el cual se realizará la búsqueda de valores distintos.
- `query`: Es un documento que especifica los documentos de los cuales se desea obtener los valores distintos.
- `options`: Es un documento opcional para configurar las [opciones](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#distinct-method-options) de la consulta.

Así para construir la consulta, el campo sobre el cual realizar la búsqueda será `respuestas` y el documento del que deseamos extraer la información será el que tenga `_id` igual a `5c6af0edb02ea75fb848dc61`.

Entonces, podrías realizar tu consulta de la siguiente manera: (asumiendo que tu colección se llama preguntas)

```
> db.preguntas.distinct("respuestas",{"_id" : ObjectId("5c6af0edb02ea75fb848dc61")});
```

Una captura de pantalla usando los datos que has provisto en la pregunta:

[image: Ejemplo de uso de DISTINCT MongoDB]

Supongamos que deseas almacenar el resultado en una variable en Mongo, lo puedes hacer asignando a una variable el comando, de la siguiente manera:

```
> let resultado = db.preguntas.distinct("respuestas",{"_id" : ObjectId("5c6af0edb02ea75fb848dc61")});
```

Una captura de pantalla del resultado anterior:

[image: Ejemplo de DISTINCT almecenando resultado en una variable]

Espero que esto aclare tu duda.